# Assign char to array of chars inside an struct thats inside a array of structs thats inside a array of structs thats inside a array of struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I need to simulate a hard disk for a college assignment. I have a char array inside a struct, another struct has an array of the last struct and so on. The teacher asked for it to be done this way.

```
typedef struct block {
    unsigned char bytes_s[512];
} block;

typedef struct  sectror_array {
   block sector[60];
} sectror_array;

typedef struct track_array {
    sectror_array track[5];
} track_array;
```

All of that in a

```
track_array cylinder[10];
```

declared as global.

my problem is that i can't seem to access any of these. In my code, i use a loop to assign a variable to the "byte" and then try to print it

```
int c=0, t=0, s=0, b=0;
  while(c<11){
    if(b==512){
      b=0;
      s++;
      if(s==60){
        s=0;
        t++;
        if(t==5){
          t=0;
          c++;
          if(c==10){
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    cylinder[c].track[t].sector[s].bytes_s[b]=0;
    b++;
    printf("%d %d %d %d, %c\n",c, t, s ,b, 
    cylinder[c].track[t].sector[s].bytes_s[b]);
```

But it shows nothing even as i tryed to assign 'a' to every byte.

Yet it compiles and runs without crashes.

Never had to work with such before and i'm out of ideas of how to fix this.

https://github.com/diceEviscerator/trabOA

code is my_drive.cpp

saved as cpp but is pure c (needed to save as cpp to run gtest)

Comment: Can you show us the `for()` statements (or whatever) you're using to loop `j`, `t`, and `s` through their defined ranges?

Comment: Maybe it won't enter the loop because the condition is false?

Comment: Maybe you need to do some debugging work yourself. I guarantee the problem has nothing to do with nested arrays of structs.

Comment: its long, so i didnt wanted to include on the question, but sure

This is for find the empty cluster (of 4 sectors)

all the variables are integers.
 
    while(cylinder[j].track[t].sector[s*4].bytes_s[0]!=0){
       s++;
       if(s==15){
         j++;
         s=0;
         if(j==10){
           t++;
           j=0;
           if(t==5){
             printf("Disk full\n");
             return;
           }
         }
       }
     }

Comment: dont have much debugging experience, the program runs swftlly so i dont see anything on gdb, how can i use it to analyse the program?

Comment: https://github.com/diceEviscerator/trabOA/blob/master/include/drive_lib.h
https://github.com/diceEviscerator/trabOA/blob/master/src/my_drive.cpp

complete code as asked, saved as cpp but is pure c (needed to save as cpp to run gtest)

Comment: We didn't ask full code, but a [mcve]. Whatever it's better than nothing.

Comment: You assigned to byte b, then incremented b, then tried to print out the byte indexed by b.

Answer (score 2):

`while (cylinder[j].track[t].sector[s * 4].bytes_s[0] != 0) {`

> The program just won't simply enter the loop.
>
> I tried to "initialize" the struct by making a loop that would assign 0 to every byte

So, an extremely simplified version of what you describe looks like this?

```
int main (void)
{
   int x = 0;          // Initialize to 0

   while ( x != 0 )    // While not 0, do some work
   {
      x = 1;
   }
}
```

Break your problem down into small parts and code it in small increments, verifying each as you go.  "Big Bang" coding adds too much complexity at once and makes problems much harder to find.

Comment: This loop should not run directly as the program starts with an empty disk, so the "find first empty loop" should'nt run on the first file entered. So the code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

So far the problem is that i was tring to print the character after the one i changed

```
cylinder[c].track[t].sector[s].bytes_s[b]=0;
b++;
printf("%d %d %d %d, %c\n",c, t, s ,b, cylinder[c].track[t].sector[s].bytes_s[b]);
```

where should be:

```
cylinder[c].track[t].sector[s].bytes_s[b]=0;
printf("%d %d %d %d, %c\n",c, t, s ,b, cylinder[c].track[t].sector[s].bytes_s[b]);
b++;
```

there are still problems with this code but this problem seems solved. It wasn't clear to me at the time I posted and I wish i could delete since it is so simple thus is no new knowledge , but i can't.